Procedure que Retorna Multiples Tablas en SQL y pandas
Tengo la siguiente Funcion en Python que me retorna
def retornarActaGrupo(self,stGrupo):

        stQuery = f"""
                        exec sp_get_NuevaActaAsamblea_SMV  '{stGrupo}','1'
                """

        dfActaGrupo = pd.array(pd.read_sql(stQuery, self.vConexion))

        return dfActaGrupo

Esta funcion ejecuta el Procedure sp_get_NuevaActaAsamblea_SMV, el cual me devuelve varias tablas cuando lo ejecuto en MySQLManagement:

Sin embargo, cuando lo ejecuto con la libreria Pandas y su funcion read_sql solo me devuelve la primera tabla. Quiero retornar todas las tablas que devuelve el procedure para poder procesarlas.
Por favor su ayuda

Consulta como se utiliza la función nextset() en la documentación en Python: https://peps.python.org/pep-0249/#nextset. Un ejemplo en como utilizarlo sería:
# recuperar filas del primer conjunto
rows = cursor.fetchall()    
# Procesar las primeras filas establecidas aquí.

# avanzar al siguiente conjunto de resultados
while (cursor.nextset()):    
    # recuperar filas del siguiente conjunto, descartando la primera.
    rows = cursor.fetchall()    
    # Procesar las siguientes filas aquí


Graciaaaas. Me funciono y ahora si puedo ver mis datos de todas las tablas.
